# After deleting a tenant, it is not possible to create a tenant with the same name WSO2 IS 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am running WSO2 IS 5.0.0. I have the SP for IS 5.0.0 applied along with all the other security patches issued for that version for Identity Server and Carbon 4.2.0. My environment consists of 4 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines).
I am using the following two SOAP services to handle the tenant management:
1. TenantMgtAdminService
2. RemoteTenantManagerService
However once I delete a tenant programmatically and then try to create a tenant with the same name, I get an error saying that tenant with the same name already exists. It seems to be some sort of cache, because if I delete the tenant, restart the Identity Server system and then try to create tenant with the same name everything goes well and the tenant is created.
Is there any way to fix this or workaround it?
It is quite frustrating especially when it comes to acceptance testing, because the test suit is executed, then it cleans all the inserted data and when is triggered for second time, errors are thrown that such tenant already exists.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete Tenants, You can only disable the tenants. (make them inactive)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.